# Issue while deploying asp.net core application using powershell

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, powershell-3.0, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core web application that is hosted in IIS. We also have build server used for continuous integration using Jenkins. Jenkins get latest from GitHub and builds & publish the project in local folder and then execute powershell script to copy published folder to web server. ( it simply copies the files from local folder to network folder using Copy-Item)

The powershell script first stops the `remote` IIS web site before copying the file. (and i have confirmed that the remote web site is indeed stopped before deploying)

However every now and then we get error while copying files

> Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file
>   `\\some_ip\_apps\myapp\UI\UI.dll` because it is being used by another
>   process.

So i have downloaded [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to check who is accessing this file on web server and i turned out its `dotnet.exe`

How do i stop `dotnet.exe` remotely or how do i release the handle remotely using powershell

[image]

Comment: Feels like you are reinventing the wheel. Why not just use [Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#deploy-the-app) and be done with it?

Comment: well the article says `Files in the publish folder are locked when the app is running. Locked files can't be overwritten. To release locked files in a deployment, stop the app pool` so even with Web Deploy i have to manually or using PS stop the app pool

Comment: It also says that Web Deploy is an alternative to PowerShell for unlocking them (and I have used it and never had an issue with locking). It is pick one of the 3 options, not use all 3.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments about using WebDeploy to simplify your approach a little.

As far as powershell goes the [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1) and [Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-5.1) along with normal Remoting stuff will let you shut down dotnet.exe.